# How to automate test google analytics on every event fired using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, google-analytics, selenium-webdriver

I am working on Google Analytics automation test with Selenium WebDriver java bindings. Our site has Google Analytics tracking events set on important elements on the site. I need to verify that on clicking a certain element under test, the Google Analytic event is in fact fired.

I'm testing it on FireFox. When I click F12, I can see in the console that a Google Analytics is fired with message `GET http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif` on each element click event.

```
    SampleCode :-
      WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();
      wd.get("http://www.dummyExample.com/");
      wd.findElement(By.linkText("Document Referece")).click();
      wd.findElement(By.id("Ex2vc2")).click();
```

How can I achieve this task? I have googled it but could not find good answers. If anyone can help me with some references or sample code I would be very Thankful.

Comment: This is just testing Google's Analytics JavaScript (which Google will already do!). I don't understand how this achieves anything.

Comment: @Arran : I want to capture in the log that which click event has google analytics.

Answer (score 4):

1. Good way to test GA is by using javascript. Example shows tests with phantomjs, because it's faster with js stuff, but i think you could use FF or other browsers as well.
   Also Author added github link with code to try it. The main approach of test is cool, but it may take time to create code for that and support it later.

http://viget.com/extend/testing-google-analytics-with-phantomjs

2. Second way is to use HttpProxy. AFAIK there was tool - BrowserMobProxy. You'll be able to sniff all requests on testing website, but they in HAR format. So the algorithm is simple, enable proxy, open website, do actions, sniff requests, parse them and assert the values.
3. Change endpoint and save all requests to assert them. So usually analytics sends requests to the same url, like 'http://google.com/analytics' or whatever. So, you can change this behavior on testing webserver. F.e. add this url to /etc/hosts with localhost address. And then all requests on webserver which are sent to GA domain will be received by webserver.

That will require extra programming. But it's the cleanest way for testing IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using Java script command to capture the event triggered in browser and same script will capture event for different browser(tested for chrome and Firefox). 
  Basically it is the same way as we do in console window to capture event

```
**window.dataLayer[0]**.event
```

just store this value in some variable and compare with expected event, it will give the first event which got triggered and to move next event just use

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.dataLayer.shift() ");
```

which will go and capture next event.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) [charles](/questions/tagged/charles) to capture and verify analytics calls using it's [web interface / API](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/web-interface/). For example, if you wanted to check that a call to action was firing the correct event you would:

1. Start recording using the Charles API
2. Click the button using Selenium
3. Stop the recording using the Charles API
4. Retrieve the recorded session as JSON using the Charles API
5. Check for the session for the expected analytics acceptance criteria

An example video can be found [here](https://i.imgur.com/RSDGEiI.mp4).

Answer (score -1):

You can't capture the output from the console tab by pressing F12 in terms of automation.

You need to fire the click function through automation script and then you can check the list of events fired in google analytics tool. For that sign up in this URL http://www.google.com/analytics/

Set your URL and domain here. Then after executing your tests on events fired come to the analytics tool and check the output.

Comment: This answer won't work as events don't appear in Google Analytics immediately.  Also, this isn't a completely automated process since it requires checking GA manually.

Comment: This answer works. To give a bit of brief, you can run the Automation tests using the campaign URL. You have an option called report in Google analytics. You can schedule the report to arrive your mailbox every day for hits sent by your Automation script. I agree with one thing. there is no real time reporting, but you can get the report in 24 hours which is not bad.